# Generalizing methods calls using reflection in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on writing a set of methods that will allow me to provide nicely formatted output for unit tests.  The idea is that I can call one test method, passing in an array(s) of parameter values and expected return results.  The test method then executes successive calls to the method being tested, reporting back whether the return value matches the expected result.

```
// Example to test a method with 2 int parameters returning boolean
public boolean executeUnitTest(Class<?> theClass, String methodName,
                               int[] p1, int[] p2, boolean[] expected)
{
    try {
        boolean hasFail = false;
        numTests = p1.length; 
        Class[] types = { int.class, int.class };

        // Get access to the method to test
        Method method = theClass.getMethod(methodName, types);  

        String summary = "";   // To summarize the results

        // Loop on each test case
        for (int testIndex = 0; testIndex < numTests; testIndex++)
        {
            int param1 = p1[testIndex];
            int param2 = p2[testIndex];

            // invoke the method to test 
            Object o = method.invoke(null, param1, param2);  
            // save the run result as the expected return type
            boolean run = (boolean)o;                        

            // build a String with the method call and params
            // for reporting the results
            String params = param1 + "," + param2; 
            summary += methodName + "(" + params + ")" + "\n";
            String expectedS = expected[testIndex] + "";
            String runS = run + "";
            summary += "\tExpected:\t" + expectedS +"\n\tRun:\t\t" +
                        runS + "\n";

            // Check if the test passed or failed        
            boolean result = expected.equals(run);
            if (!result) {
                summary += "\tFAIL\n";
                hasFail = true;
            } else {
                summary += "\tPASS\n";
            }

        }

        System.out.println(summary);
        return hasFail;

    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And here's an example of executing this test case.
The method being tested is in the class Examples and has the method header:

```
public static boolean methodToTest(int a, int b)


public void testExample()
{
    int[] p1 = { 2,1,1,2,5 };  // parameter 1
    int[] p2 = { 2,1,2,1,6 };  // parameter 2 
    boolean[] expected = { true, true, false, false, false };
    executeUnitTest(Examples.class, "methodToTest", 
                    p1, p2, expected));
}
```

The above works perfectly and does what I want.
THE PROBLEM: I have to write a version of executeUnitTest for every possible combination of parameters and return types.
I'm trying to come up with a way to generalize the executeUnitTest code so that it will work with ANY set of parameters and return types.  Any ideas?

Here is what I have so far and where I'm being tripped up.

```
public boolean executeUnitTest(Class<?> theClass, String methodName,
                   Class[] paramTypes, // pass list of param types
                   Object[][] params,  // param packaged as 2D array 
                   Class returnType, Object[] returnVals)
{
    try {

        Method method = theClass.getMethod(methodName, paramTypes);

        // Loop on each test case
        for (int testIndex = 0; 
             testIndex < params[0].length; 
             testIndex++)
        {

            // HOW TO INVOKE THE METHOD WITHOUT INDIVIDUAL PARAMS???
            Object o = method.invoke(null, ????);

            // ETC...
        }

}
```

NOTE: I am unable to use junit features for this project

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use [parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests)?

Comment: The only reason is that I've never heard of it. :)   Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: Well, turns out that I have to run this code in an environment where I don't have access to junit.  Any ideas on if it can be accomplished without it?